# Revert last update svn

Tags: svn

I forgot to commit and then a do a update to my repo. All deleted files from previous revision were restored. How do I rollback?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible: you deleted files and then did an update and the files returned? I think you should delete files using `svn delete <filename>` to not have this problem. But, unfortunately, this is not going to help you out now...

Answer (score 1):

If you forgot to commit them, you're lost. You have to delete the files again.

How should the VCS know **what** you did if you didn't tell the VCS **that** you did it?

But this is not half as disastrous as if you had lost new stuff you implemented and forgot to commit that...

Answer (score 0):

The information about which files you had deleted is lost, unless you can scroll back your shell to see them. To prevent this from happening in the future, do an 'svn delete' on the files as soon as you decide to delete them. You would have to do a delete before a commit will actually delete the files anyway.